# Magento 2 high CPU usage after entering production mode

Tags: magento2, performance

We've been running a Magento 1 site for over 7 years and although cpu usage has been quite high, it's not been a concern as performance seemed fine even, it is a high traffic site after all.

Preparing to move over to Magento 2 we installed the latest version (2.3 at the time) and ran it in developer mode along with the M1 site with no hit on server performance.

Now we've finally switched fully to M2 and enabled production mode, wow, cpu usage has gone off the chart
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcIGK.jpg

I've followed a few suggestions on here regarding enabling caches etc and nothing improves. Thinking M2 would be a much more stable and 'optimised' system, we're not impressed at the moment!

Any suggestions would be very welcome. It's a single server, 16GB ram, 6 Core, Apache/PHP 7.2/MYSQL.

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Is debug mode turned off on M2?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply Wilson. Storage is an SSD yes. Debug mode is disabled. Hopefully these links work. https://pastebin.com/J9iFvbiA  https://imgur.com/a/NcYWCDD

Comment: Thanks for posting the additional information.  Analysis in process.

Comment: AndyS Could you post TEXT results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;  ? Please.

Comment: AndyS   Could you run this query and post TEXT results, please?  
SELECT  ENGINE,
        ROUND(SUM(data_length) /1024/1024, 1) AS "Data MB",
        ROUND(SUM(index_length)/1024/1024, 1) AS "Index MB",
        ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length)/1024/1024, 1) AS "Total MB",
        ROUND(SUM(table_rows)+0) AS "Num Rows",
        COUNT(*) "Num Tables"
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE  table_schema not in ("minformation_schema", "mperformance_schema")
    GROUP BY  ENGINE;

Comment: AndyS During the uptime reported com_create_table recorded average of 40,503 tables created per hour.  Is this normal ops every day?  The status provided started on Sat 10/17/2020 about 2 AM.

Comment: Sure thing: https://pastebin.com/k9GpiJBb Regarding normal ops, I can only say yes as it's the main website with little else on the server and traffic is fairly consistent. Weekends can be busier.

Comment: Is cache enabled?

Comment: Hi blob, cache is enabled yes. Just confirmed via CLI check.

Answer (score 1):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your OS Open Files limit,

From OS command prompt,
ulimit -n 128000 and press Enter
to enable more than 1024 Open Files as reported by ulimit -a output.
This is a dynamic variable and does not require OS restart.

For this change to be persistent across OS shutdown/restart's review this URL, please.
https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/
Use 128000 rather than 500000 as in the example.
This will enable MySQL to support 96000 open_files_limit to avoid Open Table THRASHING and manage the Apache software requirements for file activity.

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
open_files_limit=96000  # from 1024 to reduce Open Table Thrashing. 
innodb_open_files=40000  # from 407 to better support your 51 max_used_connections. 
table_open_cache=40000  # from 407 to reduce opened_tables RPS of 56. 
table_definition_cache=2400  # from 603 to reduce opened_table_definitions RPS of 23. 
innodb_io_capacity=1900  # from 200 to allow more SSD IOPS utilization.
```

Some of these variables are static and I would recommend making all of them, then SHUTDOWN and RESTART your MySQL instance.

AndyS, For your busy system there are many more areas to be considered/tuned.  Please view our profile for contact information and consider using our free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.
Comments after application are appreciated with positive/negative feedback.

Comment: Sincere thanks for your time and suggestions Wilson, I will make those changes today and monitor the server performance. I'll certainly follow your links too and hopefully learn something from this experience. Again, thank you

Comment: A quick update.CPU usage has remained high so further investigation needed https://imgur.com/a/El6ghif

Comment: A part of the answer includes - For your busy system there are many more areas to be considered/tuned.

Comment: Andys, What is result of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'uptime%'; ?  Are your queries completing faster with the reduction in opens?

Comment: Andys, Please also post TEXT results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%open%'; as well as the uptime results to allow calculation of current RatePerSecond for the variables  that will be listed. Thanks

Comment: Hi Wilson. Having some time today, I checked over things and a couple of the updates hadn't taken hold. I've created a system override file and they have taken this time. Will monitor for 24 hours. Thanks for the followup

Comment: Andys, Thanks for your comment and current status.  Looking forward to news from you tomorrow or next week since the suggestions have been implemented. Please post a new MySQLTuner report after 24 hours.

Comment: Here's the status after around 21 hours of uptime https://pastebin.com/BKYz9dNR I must admit, from the stats I keep looking at, traffic is high on this server, shame it's not reflected in orders.

Comment: Andys, the big winner in the OPENS world was reduction of Opened_tables from 156 RatePerSecond to 13 RatePerSecond.  Your system was thrashing opening tables seriously.  Have you had an opportunity to look at our website?  To reduce your CPU busy, I would recommend - https://mysqlservertuning.com/collections/shop-our-services/products/loyalty-global-status-and-global-variable-analysis  for improving speed of query completion.  Do you have Skype Talk flexibility?  My Skype ID is wlhauck@aol.com

Comment: Hi Wilson. I made other changes to the system too following the magento 2 docs. Enabling opcache and php tweaks. Also added some extra firewall rules as I found a number of scrapers calling lots of pages. I'm not sure if these made much difference but I will be monitoring and moving over to varnish cache and elasticsearch to see if they help. I'll also put your suggestion to management regarding further mysql tweaks in your link. I'm very grateful for your time on this and I hope to speak again soon. All the very best,

Comment: @AndyS Two more tips to improve performance, A) query_cache_size=0  # rather than 512M and B) net_buffer_length=256K  # from 16384 to better support your volume of bytes_received and bytes_sent.  Just 2 of the many needed changes for performance improvement.  Maybe these changes will assist in management's view of moving forward.

Comment: thank you for the continued suggestions. We're not seeing any obvious improvement at the moment. We're on MYSQL v5.7, would upgrading to v8 be of benefit do you think? https://imgur.com/a/Zvyiq0a

Comment: @AndyS What approximate date/time of day were the above changes made?

Comment: @Andys         Do you have Skype Talk available? My id is above. Let's schedule a date/time after NOON USA Central Time.  We have 9:35 AM at this time.

Comment: Changes are generally made mid morning GMT so that they can be monitored through the working day.

Comment: @AndyS The last graph posted - that included shutdown/restart shows clear reduction in cpu used.  A part of the answer includes - For your busy system there are many more areas to be considered/tuned.  To determine effective usage on linux, Percentage used / cores = effective % used.  565 / 6 = 94% effective busy.  We still need to Skype TALK and pursue additional tuning to continue to make progress.

Comment: Hi Wilson, thanks for the follow up message. I'm sure your suggestions have helped greatly with MYSQL so again, thank you for the help there. Because no significant change in cpu uage was seen we moved onto a dedicated 8 core VPS from a shared 6 core and the difference is huge. This looks to have solved our immediate issue. Best wishes, Andy

Comment: @AndyS  Stay in touch.  Happy Holidays to you, your family and your team.  Wilson

Comment: To you too Wilson, all the very best